# Router changed SSID on 2.4GHz frequency only, 5GHz stayed the same

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

We have an ASUS Black Knight Router RT-N66U with firmware version 3.0.0.4.374_720. It was running with dual bands in two frequencies, 2.4GHz and 5GHz, each with the same SSID.

However, one of the SSID's changed to a different SSID (the 2.4GHz frequency) without any changes by user, whereas the other SSID (the 5GHz frequency) stayed the same. They were both called ASUS, but the 2.4GHz frequency changed its name to `admin`.

Can anyone give an explanation as to why and as how to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: This does not happen.  So either somebody changed it or it was a software glitch.  The fact the defaults were restored indicates software glitch.  How you prevent it from happening is contacting the OEM and reproting the problem.